# Can we have Table Declaration in Snowflake similar to Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to make use of Table declaration syntax and creating the same in Snowflake SQL.

I've gone through the snowflake community & documentations and all I could find is Table variable directly being assigned similar to SQL table variable or making use of a Table function.

Comment: sorry, can't understand a word of your question. are you talking table or table function or a table variable? maybe give an example of your oracle code?

Comment: Hi, I am referring to declaring a table function. Below is an example that I want to convert to the snowflake. Also, I want to convert record declaration & make use of pragma declaration. Can it be done in Snowflake?



DECLARE
   TYPE MyTrip_table_type IS TABLE OF
       business_trips%ROWType
       INDEX BY BINARY INTEGER;
 
   myTrips MyTrip_table_type;

   BEGIN
*body statements*
   END;

DECLARE
TYPE emp_det IS RECORD
(
EMP_NO NUMBER, 
EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(150),
MANAGER NUMBER, 
SALARY NUMBER
);
emp_rec emp_det;
BEGIN
*Body Statements*
END;

Comment: DECLARE
   TYPE MyTrip_table_type IS TABLE OF
       business_trips%ROWType
       INDEX BY BINARY INTEGER;
 
   myTrips MyTrip_table_type;

   BEGIN
*body statements*
   END;

Comment: DECLARE
TYPE emp_det IS RECORD
(
EMP_NO NUMBER, 
EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(150),
MANAGER NUMBER, 
SALARY NUMBER
);
emp_rec emp_det;
BEGIN
*Body Statements*
END;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally Snowflake doesn't allow indexes nor type declarations.

other than that, you have two options:

- use JS stored procedures, but they are not meant to return a range of values, all you can do is make a temporary table and put your set in there
- use UDFs, that are (or well, can be) SQL and can return a table, but have a limited set of functionality